# Convert jquery function to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to push my Javascript knowledge and improve for my current job as a designer-developer. The other developer and I cooperated on this jQuery to alter Squarespace's default menu behavior, which is really weird. But we're loading the entire jQuery library just to accomplish this one thing.

I'd like to rewrite the code to run in plain vanilla javascript so that I don't have to load the library on every website we make, but I'm not experienced enough in Javascript to just wing through this.

Here is the code:

```
$(function () {
    if ($(window).width() > 640) {
        $(function () {
            $(".folder-parent a").each(function () {
                $(this).next().find("a").first().hide();
            });
            $(".folder-parent a").click(function () {
                window.location = $(this).next().find("a").first().attr("href");
            });
        });
    }
});
```

I see some potential issues. First off, I know the class selector will have to be rewritten, or is there another way around that? I don't have the option of adding IDs so I can use getElementsById. 
Can Javascript hop through the DOM (next, find) and so on?

I'll put up my own attempt at rewriting this code, but I was wondering if y'all had any pointers for converting code, or any pitfalls to avoid, or things like that. Thank you very much!

Andrew

EDIT: Here is my attempt in vanilla Javascript. This is literally the first function I've ever written that's not from a tutorial, so it didn't work. What am I doing wrong? I guess I left some jQuery mixed in.

```
// Function to change the default menu behavior of Squarespace. Written minus jQuery!
function fixSquarespaceNav {
    if (document.documentElement.offsetWidth > 640) { 
        var navElement = document.querySelectorAll(".folder-parent a");
        foreach (navElement) { 
            this.next().find("a").first().style.display = "none";
        }
        navElement.onclick=function(){
            window.location = this.next().find("a").first().attr("href");
        }; /* navElement */
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll

Comment: just take it one step at a time, could for instance just forcus on the window.location to begin with.

Comment: You'll find `document.querySelectorAll()` is almost exactly the same as a jQuery selector. Loop over the NodeList, and check out the source code for `find()/first()/next()` (which are conveniently in plain ol' JavaScript ;) )

Comment: Where is your own attempt? And yes, vanilla JS can certainly do all of those things.

Comment: you can also just do all of this stuff without a module.

Comment: I've updated it to include my own attempt. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more or less literal translation is

```
function fixSquarespaceNav() {
    if (document.documentElement.offsetWidth > 640) { 
        var navElements = document.querySelectorAll(".folder-parent a");
        for(var i=0, l=navElements.length; i<l; ++i)
            navElements[i]
                .nextElementSibling
                .getElementsByTagName('a')[0]
                .style.display = "none";
        for(var i=0, l=navElements.length; i<l; ++i)
            navElements[i].onclick = function(){
                window.location =
                    this
                    .nextElementSibling
                    .getElementsByTagName('a')[0]
                    .getAttribute('href');
            };
    }
}
```

But you can use

```
(function() {
    function getAnchor(el) {
        return el.nextElementSibling.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
    }
    function handler() { window.location = getAnchor(this).href; }
    return function fixSquarespaceNav() {
        var navElements = document.querySelectorAll(".folder-parent a");
        for(var i=0, l=navElements.length; i<l; ++i) {
            getAnchor(navElements[i]).style.display = "none";
            navElements[i].onclick = handler;
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: I'll look at this in more detail when I get home, but getAnchor is a helper function since it is repeated in the first code section, right?

then the function is setting the same variable, and then running the for loop which is shorter and more compact because of the getAnchor function.

Comment: @authorandrew Yes. And I use a wrapping self-executing function function to avoid possible conflict with other codes.

Comment: What does this line do?
    function handler() { window.location = getAnchor(this).href; }

Comment: @authorandrew That's the event handler. Event handlers shouldn't be defined inside loops because then a new function is recreated at each iteration. And I use `href` property instead of `href` attribute because it's the "good" way of doing it (and it's  shorter).

Comment: Gotcha. What event is it handling, exactly? window.location captures what? I can see that it's running the getAnchor function. Aha, I see! The handler function is called later on, to set the new href to the original element.

What's the difference between a property and attribute?

Comment: @authorandrew Attributes are specific to elements, you can set them in the html source and its value is a string. And a property is something every JS object can have. When there are analogous property and attribute, if you want to change or read the state of the element it's better to use properties (though using the attribute can also work). For example, with `href`, the attribute gives the string you have in the html source, but the property gives the absolute resolved path to the linked URL.

Comment: One last question then I'm done, I promise. Will this select _every_ a in my submenu, or only the first one? If only the first one, what part of the code limits that?

Comment: If you use `querySelectorAll(".folder-parent a")`, it will return a `NodeList` instance containing all `<a>` elements which are descendants of an element with class `folder-parent`. If you use `querySelector(".folder-parent a")`, it will return only the first one.

Comment: Okay. So for my purposes (removing the first child element, assigning the href to the parent link), I would want to use querySelector, right?

Comment: @authorandrew I think you need `querySelectorAll` because you want to add the event listener to each nav element and want to hide the anchor related to each one.

Comment: No, just the first one. I'm trying to alter the Squarespace menu behavior. Their submenus are folders-in most submenus the parent is also a clickable link, in SQS the parent is a folder that holds the children but doesn't actually point to a page itself. To fix this, we wrote this script to hide the first child link, and assign its href to the parent link, so that the submenu acts more like a traditional one. We account for this by adding a child that's actually the page we want the parent to go to. That child should never be visible since it would seem to duplicate the parent (same name)

Comment: @authorandrew I would understand it better what you are doing with a working demo including html code. But the jQuery code you have in your question gets **all** `.folder-parent a` elements and iterates them (explicitly with `each`, and implicitly with `click`)

Comment: I'm sorry! I got the elements confused. You're right. The script does iterate through every folder-parent a element. That's because the folder-parent a is the parent link of the submenu. It is supposed to iterate through every one of these. What I was thinking of was the .nextSiblingElement which selects the first A in the submenu. As far as a code example, I can give you block-church.squarespace.com, but nothing more than that. We build all of our products on SquareSpace (not my choice)

Comment: @authorandrew Does it produce any error in the console?

Comment: No error at all, oddly. It's almost like it's not even running, but it's wrapped in a self-running function, isn't it? (Apologies for letting it sit this long, I've been using the jQuery code in production until now just because I haven't had time to look at this).

Comment: @authorandrew No idea, sorry. I could help more if you could provide a demo

Comment: I can't put the non-functioning code on any of our production sites, but let me see what I can do with a demo site.

Comment: Okay, here we go: https://talladega-demo.squarespace.com/ I pasted in the exact code that you provided above, except I changed '.folder-parent a' to '.folder > a' to match document structure. In that line, I am selecting the parent a, correct? 
My only other thought for what this could be is if I'm not initializing this properly. I'm pretty new to javascript, and feel very lost.

Comment: I think it's working, isn't it? If I click "SO Test Dropdown", I go to "/so-test-dropdown-should-be-hidden/"

Comment: Ah, but that's the default Squarespace behavior. The original script assigned that link (needlessly, I guess, since Squarespace does it by default) and hides the first nav item.